# Override function

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In woocommerce plugin file `class-wc-booking-cart-manager.php` there is this code

```
/**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', array( $this, 'add_cart_item' ), 10, 1 );
        }

/**
     * Adjust the price of the booking product based on booking properties
     *
     * @param mixed $cart_item
     * @return array cart item
     */
    public function add_cart_item( $cart_item ) {
        if ( ! empty( $cart_item['booking'] ) && ! empty( $cart_item['booking']['_cost'] ) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['booking']['_cost'] );
        }
        return $cart_item;
    }
```

I want to change `add_cart_item` function's code into my child theme `functions.php` file. I want to know how to override this plugin function.

So I did this :

```
remove_all_filters('woocommerce_add_cart_item');
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'custom_add_cart_item');

function custom_add_cart_item($cart_item) {
    if (empty( $cart_item['booking'] ) && empty( $cart_item['booking']['_cost'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( 2000 );
    }
    return $cart_item;
}
```

As you can see, I'm setting price to 2000.

But it does not work.. Thanks for your help !

Comment: it is possible that you are trying to remove the filter before it was set.

Comment: Here `$cart_item` is array OR object?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for overriding price of product in cart

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `woocommerce_add_cart_item`, Please use `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_add_cart_item' );

function custom_add_cart_item( $cart_object ) {
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        if ( empty( $value['booking'] ) && empty( $value['booking']['_cost'] ) {
            $value['data']->price = 2000;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that this code is always executable. After adding this code.